# Read-the-Docs Local Instance: Docs are built successfully but cannot be found eror (404)

Tags: docker, python-3.6, read-the-docs

I have successfully installed an instance of Read-the-Docs locally and integrated with the public instance of Github.

I have successfully imported and built three projects (even a private one after some minor code alterations, though it is not normally supported). One of these projects is the default template project that RTD suggests for testing.

I can view the docs in the machine where the RTD instance is installed. However, when I press the green "View Docs" button a 404 status code occurs. Supposedly, the docs should be under /docs/template/en/latest. As you can see there is no docs prefix in the available URLs:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlmLy.png)

My assumption was that the endpoints regarding the docs are updated dynamically and the Django application reloads, yet I have been searching the code and I have not found anything to support this assumption.

My question is, if anyone has ever come upon this issue and how / if it was resolved?